# What actually provides all the electrons in the electric grid?

Tags: electricity

It seems Electric generators don't create electrons, they just push them around the whole grid? If a Wind turbine is built and adds 1MW to the grid, did any new electrons need to be 'added'? Do all the copper wirings already have enough electrons in their "sea", s.t. even if I added 1 million Wind turbines we'd still have plenty of electrons to push around ?

Comment: The electrons don’t get used up. They return to ‘ground’, ready to go around again. But there are so many everywhere that you will never run out.

Comment: I did not say they get used up. I am asking what material/source actually provide the bulk of electrons in the electric grid. "There are so many" - from where?  The copper in the wires ? The air? etc?

For my learning- why was this question downvoted?

Comment: Every atom of a conductor has at least one electron which is free to move. so maybe look up how many Cu atoms are in a short thin wire.

Answer (score 1):

Every atom within a wire possesses sufficient electrons to facilitate the flow of current, but it's important to note that there are different types of currents, such as Direct Current (DC) and Alternating Current (AC).

DC can be likened to a closed system involving a water tank, a water pump, a water tower, and a water turbine to generate electricity. In this analogy, the water molecules represent the electrons, continually circulating within the system. The water pump corresponds to the charger, while the tank acts as the battery. Notably, no additional water needs to be added to the system. Similarly, in a DC circuit, the flow of electrons remains consistent in one direction, without the need for any external replenishment.

On the other hand, AC also operates without any additional substances being introduced. Instead, an inductor generates an electron flow in one direction, and then swiftly reverses the flow in the opposite direction. This oscillating current causes the pre-existing electrons to move back and forth about 60 times per second. It's crucial to understand that although the electrons do not travel the entire length of the wire, they effectively transmit energy (current) to the other end without the need for additional electrons.

Answer (score 0):

All atoms are neutral  , and have a nucleus with the number of positive charge equal to the number of the electrons in the orbitals around the nucleus.

In bulk solid  matter there is an e[normous number of atoms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mole_(unit)) and it depends on the type of solid how and if  a current appears under an electric potential. This is a [microscopic view](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/electric/miccur.html) of current in a conductor.

[image: current]

Rather complicated and cannot be answered in a few words, but the electrons come from the nuclei, participating in complicated latices of atoms.